# Timezone format, how to know the timezone

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, timezone-offset

I got a timestamp in the following format:

```
2017-09-27T16:19:24+0000
```

How do I know which timezone that is? What's the `DateTimeFormatter` if I'm using Java 8?

Comment: Your input is a raw String? Do you want the timezone or the time offset? Obviously, with the offset only, there is no magic to get the timezone with solely this information

Comment: @Al1 yes, it's raw string. I thought there's some sort of datetime mask available? but which timezone is this?

Comment: +0000 clearly tells you that its converted in to UTC.

Comment: @Optional I see, so, the benchmark will always be UTC?

Comment: @musicsquad You have to see the last char after + to know the time is in which timezone. e.g +0530 will mean Indian Standard time zone or so.

Comment: @Optional I mean, if it's +0530, then that means 5 hours 30 mins ahead of UTC, correct? that's what I mean by "benchmark is UTC"

Comment: You can kinda guess which timezone it is based on the offset, but you may run into parts of the world with identical time offsets that use different DST rules.

Comment: For example, UTC is +0000 year round, but Europe/London is only +0000 from late October to late March.

Comment: @Powerlord I see, I assume that's cause man made DST? thanks for the explanation

Comment: @musicsquad yesl

Comment: @musicsquad Actually, man made both UTC and DST. Anyway, you can't know exactly what's the timezone based only in the offset. More than one timezone can use the [same offset at the same time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets). The best you can do is to get a list of possible zones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ZonedDateTime**

As you stated using Java 8, you can leverage ZonedDateTime by using

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-09-27T16:19:24+0000", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

Parsing rules are explained in [DateTimeFormatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). It is not exactly the [`ISO 8601 ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) as the offset should have been written `+00:00` instead of `+0000`

**Time zone vs time offset**

Then, you can get the **offset** information with `zdt.getZone()`. However, you'll only get the [Offset ID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#getId--):

> - Z - for UTC (ISO-8601)
> - +hh:mm or -hh:mm - if the seconds are zero (ISO-8601)
> - +hh:mm:ss or -hh:mm:ss - if the seconds are non-zero (not ISO-8601)

As one comment said, be careful that *time offset is not time zone*: A given time zone (e.g. time in France) does not have the same offset the whole year (summer time vs winter time).

Comment: As the input has only the offset, and no timezone information, you could also use `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

The timestamp given has a timezone offset (`+0000`), which represents +00 hours and +00 minutes from GMT+00.

This timezone pattern can be represented by the character `Z` for both [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)'s `ofPattern` method.

The timezone you are handling can be represented by a pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`:

- `yyyy` represents the current year
- `MM` represents the month of the current year
- `dd` represents the current day of the current month
- `'T'` represents a quoted `T` character
- `HH` represents the current hour of the current day
- `mm` represents the current minute of the current hour
- `ss` represents the current second of the current minute
- `Z` represents the timezone offset from GMT

Comment: GMT and UTC is consistent throughout the year, correct?

Comment: Yes. Although some timezones experience DST, GMT and UTC are constant and timezones change relative to that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ISO 8601 format: dateTime±hhmm. Here hhmm is offset from UTC

Answer (score 1):

The representation 2017-09-27T16:19:24+0000 gives +0000 so baseline UTC.

Timestamps themselves and LocalDateTime wrap a long count of seconds and do not contain a separate time zone info.

Java provides a [class that maintains an addition time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
ZonedDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Sofia"));
```

One needs to be sure that the time was stored as UTC, +0000: a recommendation only.